# Imperative to Functional

Tags: f#

I have been doing a CodeWars exercise which can also be seen at [dev.to](https://dev.to/thepracticaldev/daily-challenge-126-the-supermarket-line-c97).

The essence of it is:

```
There is a line for the self-checkout machines at the supermarket. Your challenge is to write a function that calculates the total amount of time required for the rest of the customers to check out!

INPUT
customers : an array of positive integers representing the line. Each integer represents a customer, and its value is the amount of time they require to check out.
n : a positive integer, the number of checkout tills.

RULES
There is only one line serving many machines, and
The order of the line never changes, and
The front person in the line (i.e. the first element in the array/list) proceeds to a machine as soon as it becomes free.

OUTPUT
The function should return an integer, the total time required.
```

The answer I came up with works - but it is highly imperative.

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq

let getQueueTime (customerArray: int list) n =
    let mutable d = new Dictionary<string,int>()
    for i in 1..n do
        d.Add(sprintf "Line%d" <| i, 0) 

    let getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName(d:Dictionary<string,int>) =
        let mutable lowestValue = -1
        let mutable lineName = ""
        for myLineName in d.Keys do
            let myValue = d.Item(myLineName)
            if lowestValue = -1 || myValue <= lowestValue then
              lowestValue <- myValue
              lineName <- myLineName
        lineName

    for x in customerArray do
        let lineName = getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName d
        let lineTotal = d.Item(lineName)
        d.Item(lineName) <- lineTotal + x

    d.Values.Max()
```

So my question is ... is this OK F# code or should it be written in a functional way?  And if the latter, how? (I started off trying to do it functionally but didn't get anywhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this OK F# code or should it be written in a functional way?

That's a subjective question, so can't be answered. I'm assuming, however, that since you're doing an *exercise*, it's in order to learn. Learning functional programming takes years for most people (it did for me), but F# is a great language because it enables you learn gradually.

You can, however, simplify the algorithm. Think of a *till* as a number. The number represents the *instant* it's ready. At the beginning, you initialise them all to `0`:

```
let tills = List.replicate n 0
```

where `n` is the number of tills. At the beginning, they're all ready at time `0`. If, for example, `n` is `3`, the tills are:

```
> List.replicate 3 0;;
val it : int list = [0; 0; 0]
```

Now you consider the next customer in the line. For each customer, you have to pick a till. You pick the one that is available first, i.e. with the lowest number. Then you need to 'update' the list of counters.

In order to do that, you'll need a function to 'update' a list at a particular index, which isn't part of the base library. You can define it yourself, however:

```
module List =
    let set idx v = List.mapi (fun i x -> if i = idx then v else x)
```

For example, if you want to 'update' the second element to `3`, you can do it like this:

```
> List.replicate 3 0 |> List.set 1 3;;
val it : int list = [0; 3; 0]
```

Now you can write a function that updates the set of tills given their current state and a customer (represented by a duration, which is also a number).

```
let next tills customer =
    let earliestTime = List.min tills
    let idx = List.findIndex (fun c -> earliestTime = c) tills
    List.set idx (earliestTime + customer) tills
```

First, the `next` function finds the `earliestTime` in `tills` by using `List.min`. Then it finds the index of that value. Finally, it 'updates' that till by adding its current state to the customer duration.

Imagine that you have two tills and the customers `[2;3;10]`:

```
> List.replicate 2 0;;
val it : int list = [0; 0]

> List.replicate 2 0 |> fun tills -> next tills 2;;
val it : int list = [2; 0]

> List.replicate 2 0 |> fun tills -> next tills 2 |> fun tills -> next tills 3;;
val it : int list = [2; 3]

> List.replicate 2 0 |> fun tills -> next tills 2 |> fun tills -> next tills 3
  |> fun tills -> next tills 10;;
val it : int list = [12; 3]
```

You'll notice that you can keep calling the `next` function for all the customers in the line. That's called a *fold*. This gives you the final state of the tills. The final step is to return the value of the till with the highest value, because that represents the time it finished. The overall function, then, is:

```
let queueTime line n =
    let next tills customer =
        let earliestTime = List.min tills
        let idx = List.findIndex (fun c -> earliestTime = c) tills
        List.set idx (earliestTime + customer) tills
    let tills = List.replicate n 0
    let finalState = List.fold next tills line
    List.max finalState
```

Here's some examples, taken from the original exercise:

```
> queueTime [5;3;4] 1;;
val it : int = 12

> queueTime [10;2;3;3] 2;;
val it : int = 10

> queueTime [2;3;10] 2;;
val it : int = 12
```

This solution is based entirely on immutable data, and all functions are [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so that's a functional solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that resembles your version, with all the mutability removed:

```
let getQueueTime (customerArray: int list) n =
    let updateWith f key map =
        let v = Map.find key map
        map |> Map.add key (f v)

    let initialLines = [1..n] |> List.map (fun i -> sprintf "Line%d" i, 0) |> Map.ofList

    let getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName(d:Map<string,int>) =
        let lowestLine = d |> Seq.minBy (fun l -> l.Value)
        lowestLine.Key

    let lines =
        customerArray
        |> List.fold (fun linesState x ->
            let lineName = getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName linesState
            linesState |> updateWith (fun l -> l + x) lineName) initialLines

    lines |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.Value) |> Seq.max

getQueueTime [5;3;4] 1 |> printfn "%i"
```

Those loops with mutable "outer state" can be swapped for either recursive functions or `folds`/`reduce`, here I suspect recursive functions would be nicer.

I've swapped out `Dictionary` for the immutable `Map`, but it feels like more trouble than it's worth here.

**Update** - here is a compromise solution I think reads well:

```
let getQueueTime (customerArray: int list) n =
    let d = [1..n] |> List.map (fun i -> sprintf "Line%d" i, 0) |> dict

    let getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName(d:IDictionary<string,int>) =
        let lowestLine = d |> Seq.minBy (fun l -> l.Value)
        lowestLine.Key

    customerArray
    |> List.iter (fun x ->
        let lineName = getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName d
        d.Item(lineName) <- d.Item(lineName) + 1)

    d.Values |> Seq.max

getQueueTime [5;3;4] 1 |> printfn "%i"
```

I believe there is a more natural functional solution if you approach it freshly, but I wanted to evolve your current solution.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question but I am curious as to whether you think this is better F# code? (and if so, why?).  It doesn't seem as obvious (without more detailed analysis) exactly what it is doing.  Both functions (imperative and functional) provide the same answer.

Comment: I won't try and argue that, as I wasn't trying to write code better, I just made it immutable. In the 2nd solution I've added, it seems like the more pragmatic option. I would say it's simpler as the mutable state in `getNextAvailableSupermarketLineName` wasn't immediately obvious what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is less an attempt at answering than an extended comment on Mark Seemann's otherwise [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127416). If we do not restrict ourselves to standard library functions, the slightly cumbersome determination of the index with `List.findIndex` can be avoided. Instead, we may devise a function that replaces the first occurrence of a value in a list with a new value.

The implementation of our bespoke `List.replace` involves recursion, with an accumulator to hold the values before we encounter the first occurrence. When found, the accumulator needs to be reversed and also to have the new value and the tail of the original list appended. Both of this can be done in one operation: `List.fold` being fed the new value and tail of the original list as initial state while the elements of the accumulator are prepended in the loop, thereby restoring their order.

```
module List =
    // Replace the first occurrence of a specific object in a list
    let replace oldValue newValue source =
        let rec aux acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | x::xs when x = oldValue ->
            (newValue::xs, acc)
            ||> List.fold (fun xs x -> x::xs) 
        | x::xs -> aux (x::acc) xs
        aux [] source

let queueTime customers n =
    (List.init n (fun _ -> 0), customers)
    ||> List.fold (fun xs customer ->
        let x = List.min xs
        List.replace x (x + customer) xs )
    |> List.max

queueTime [5;3;4] 1     // val it : int = 12
queueTime [10;2;3;3] 2  // val it : int = 10
queueTime [2;3;10] 2    // val it : int = 12
```